# JQuery document + each + on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just wondering if I can use .each() method with .on() in JQuery like so :

```js
$(document).each.on("change","input[type='color']",function(){});
```

I may be not even close to the right solution since I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery

Actually the thing I need in my website is that I need to get every input[type='color'] in the modal and on change of each of it, write the value of every of input in the textbox

This is the code from my function :

```js
$(document).on("click","#createTheme",function(){
    $("#createThemeDialog").css("display","block");
    $("input[type='color']").each.on("change",function(){
        var css=$(this).attr("name")+"{"+$(this).attr("label")+":"+$(this).val()+"!important}";
        $("#output").val($("#output").text()+css);
    });
});
```

But the output is only one value of a changed input[type='color']

So, is there any way to make #output display value of the every input[type='color'] on change of each input[type='color'] and update it dynamically on change?

Thank you very much for spending your precious time with my problem!
Thank you very much for any help!

Solved by @gurvinder372

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You don't need `each()` at all. `on()` will automatically bind to all elements in the collection

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I'll try it ASAP!

Comment: Generally a bad practice to add event listeners inside other event handlers unless there is a good reason and you fully understand the implications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there any way to make #output display value of the every
>   `input[type='color']` on change of `each input[type='color']` and update
>   it dynamically on change?

You can delegate the `change` event for all `input[type='color']` and use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to return the same generate string for all of them.

```
$( document ).on( "change","input[type=color]",function(){
   //now get the values from all "input[type=color]"
   var css = $( "input[type=color]" ).map( function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      return $this.attr("name") + "{" + $this.attr("label") + ":" + $this.val() + "!important}"; //the same string you were generating
   }).get().join( "," );
   $("#output").val( css );
});
```

Comment: That's the prefect solution, it works just like I want it to! Thank you very much!